# iterative scheme using taylor series

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, fixed-point-theorems

i want to derive the following iterative scheme.

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)+f(x_n)}  $$ 
where $n$  $=$  $0$$,$$1$$,$$.$$.$$.$

I think this scheme can be drive from Taylor's series but i didn't know how to approach.
I already drive some iterative schemes using Taylor series like Householders,Halley's method and some other iterative schemes.How to approach to get this iterative scheme?

Comment: [$x_{n+1}=x_n-g(x_n)/g'(x_n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) with $g(x)=e^x f(x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have looks exactly like newton's method, except with an extra $f(x)$ in the denominator. One way to derive such a form would be to choose some $g(x)$ such that $(g f)' = g f' + g f$, which is, well, a clear sign of an exponential. So choosing $h(x) = \mathrm{e}^{x} f(x)$ and applying newton's method we have:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{h(x)}{h'(x)} = x_n - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x} f(x)}{\mathrm{e}^x f'(x) + \mathrm{e}^x f(x)} = x_n - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x) + f(x)}$$

Note that since $\mathrm{e}^x$ "adds" no additional zeroes using newton's method in this way will still converge to $f(x)$'s zeroes.